# How to parse float variable from 1 .swift file to another swift file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parsing

I have 2 .swift files. One is a viewcontroller `(ViewController.swift)` The other one has a function to get data via JSSON. `(WeatherGetter.swift)`

I want to display data from the json function `(WeatherGetter.swift)` to the viewcontroller `(ViewController.swift)`. I've seen a lot of ways to do this but I can't get them to work. Can anyone provide a snippet code in swift for iOS to do this properly?

So 1 float variable which contains the wind direction needs to be displayed in the other file.

I tried:

`let wind = ViewController()
 wind.getWindDeg(windDeg: name2 as! Float)`

to send the name2 variable as windDeg var and read it in the other .swift file as:

```
func getWindDeg(windDeg: Float) {
        print(windDeg)
    }
```

This works in the debug as a print, but when I want to put it into a textfield or textlabel it crashes the app or it won't work because it is an Float. When I try to convert the float to an string it won't work either. It dispays as 0.0

So then I found something called prepareForSegue, so I gave that an try but because WeatherGetter.swift has no viewcontroller, it doesn't work I guess:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "LoadApp") {
            // pass data to next view
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ViewController {
                destinationVC.numberToDisplay = counter
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the JSON code to get the data:

if let nestedDictionary = dictionary["currently"] as? [String: Any] {

```
                        //print("test")
                        //access nested dictionary values by key
```

if let name2 = nestedDictionary["windBearing"]{
                                print("WindRichting: (name2)")

```
                            let wind = ViewController()
                            (name2 as NSString?)?.floatValue
                            self.naampje = name2 as! Float

                            //print("Uiteindelijke windrichting2: \(self.naampje)")

                        }
```

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: @Joshua I have updated my post, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: so how do you convert it to float? have you debug when your app before you convert it to a string if its the actual value?

Comment: This is the code I have, I directly convert it to Float when I parse the json data:

`let wind = ViewController()
                                wind.getWindDeg(windDeg: name2 as! Float)
                                self.naampje = name2 as! Float`

When I change it to as! String and do the same in the getWinDeg function, it gives me the error: Cannot assign value of Type 'String' to type 'Foat'

Comment: have you tried `yourlabel.text = windDeg.description`?

Comment: I can print this, that works. But I can't do it like this: `txtWindDeg.text = windDeg.description`. Than it crashes the app: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-06-15 08:59:02.021430+0200 WindApp[2582:666322] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: just basically means windDeg is nil. so your name2 as! float does not work. it passes a nil value. why not use `(name2 as NSString?)?.floatValue`

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I get 'Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to type 'NSString?' in Coercion. I have posted the JSON code in my first post, maybe there is something that needs to be changed when using this code.

Comment: @Joshua I hope you still have an idea to solve this?

Comment: What do you expect on your data? i was assuming it was a string thats why I used NSString to convert it to floatValue.  options will be handle each object by having to check if its type double or string or convert any object to string and then perform the nsstring to float conversion

Comment: @Joshua I expect the data to work with my compass heading. It needs to point to the winddirection. That part of the code does work when fill in manually, so now I need to get the JSON data there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue. I took all the code to the main ViewController.swift, now it works. Anyway thanks Joshua for your help :).